# Preview TikZ figure in AUCTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, emacs, auctex, preview

I am using AUCTeX on Emacs. When invoking `preview.el` with e.g. `C-c C-p C-p` I obtain previews of external figures (`figure` environment with `.ps` files), but not of TikZ pictures.

Is it possible to obtain previews of figures drawn with TikZ?

Comment: Try using PDF mode: select Command->TeXing Options->PDF Mode from the menu, or press C-c C-t C-p.

Answer (score 9):

With

```lisp
(eval-after-load "preview"
  '(add-to-list 'preview-default-preamble "\\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}" t)
  )
```

in your `.emacs` file, you can include the `tikzpicture` environments in the preview building process.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't work for me... I tried on Aquamacs+ MacTex. Everything is good by default. So strange.

Comment: @XxXxX It works for me with a recent GNU Emacs and AUCTeX, and I cannot test on a Max. Could you check whether the variable `preview-default-preamble` is successfully changed? Load a TeX file and do `C-h v preview-default-preamble`. It should give you something like `preview-default-preamble is a variable defined in preview.el.
Its value is ("\\RequirePackage["
 ("," . preview-default-option-list)
 "]{preview}[2004/11/05]" "\\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}")`

Comment: @sebschub it works for me flawlessly, AucTeX + emacs 24.3 in ubuntu 13.10